# AAD B2C:Unable to Authenticate web api after changing Authority URL from login.microsoftonline.com to xyz.b2clogin.com

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c

Unable to authenticate Web Api(.Net Core) after changing the Authority URL from login.microsoftonline.com to xyz.b2clogin.com

Authority Old URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/xyz.onmicrosoft.com/SignInPolicy/v2.0

Authority New URL: https://xyz.b2clogin.com/tfp/xyz.onmicrosoft.com/SignInPolicy/v2.0

Startup Code

```
.AddJwtBearer(AzureJwtSchemes.AZURE_ADB2C_AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME, options =>
    {
    options.Authority = azureB2COptions.Authority;
    options.Audience = azureB2COptions.ClientId;
    }
```

Any help will be really appreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you have a policy id in the URL? The authority is usually e.g. `https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/tfp/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_sign_up_or_in/v2.0`

Comment: Also, what errors do you receive? You can check if your authority URL is one that might work by adding `/.well-known/openid-configuration` to the end of the URL and accessing it through your browser. If the correct metadata shows up, then it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your Azure AD B2C-enabled applications and APIs may refer to `login.microsoftonline.com` in several places. For example, your code might have references to **user flows** and **token endpoints**. Make sure all of them have been updated to `your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com`.

Reference:

[Set redirect URLs to b2clogin.com for Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin)

Answer (score 0):

Might be caused by another error. 
To check what's really happening you can do the ff:

> 1. Create your custom method and setup the **OnAuthenticationFailed** under the options.Event.
> 2. Set the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII to
>      **true**
> 3. Add a breakpoint to the **AuthenticationFailedContext**

Should give you an idea on what's wrong.